# access thread_local variable in inline assembly

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86, thread-local-storage

I'm dealing with some C++ code that has an optimised version that uses inline assembly.
The optimised version is exhibiting behaviour that is not thread safe, which can be traced to 3 global variables that are accessed extensively from inside the assembly.

```
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE_MESS[16];
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) thread_local unsigned char SHAVITE_PTXT[8*4];
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE_CNTS[4] = {0,0,0,0};
```

...

```
asm ("movaps xmm0, SHAVITE_PTXT[rip]");
asm ("movaps xmm1, SHAVITE_PTXT[rip+16]");
asm ("movaps xmm3, SHAVITE_CNTS[rip]");
asm ("movaps xmm4, SHAVITE256_XOR2[rip]");
asm ("pxor   xmm2,  xmm2");
```

I naively thought that the simplest way to solve this would be to make the variables thread_local, however this leads to segfaults in the assembly - it appears that the assembly does not know that the variables are thread local?

I have dug around in the assembly of a small thread_local test case to see how gcc deals with them `mov eax, DWORD PTR fs:num1@tpoff` and tried to modify the code to do the same:

```
asm ("movaps xmm0, fs:SHAVITE_PTXT@tpoff");
asm ("movaps xmm1, fs:SHAVITE_PTXT@tpoff+16");
asm ("movaps xmm3, fs:SHAVITE_CNTS@tpoff");
asm ("movaps xmm4, fs:SHAVITE256_XOR2@tpoff");
asm ("pxor   xmm2,  xmm2");
```

Which works if all variables are also thread_local, it also matches the reference implementation (non assembly) so appears to work successfully.
However this seems very CPU specific, if I look at the output for compiling with `-m32` I get instead `mov eax, DWORD PTR gs:num1@ntpoff`

As the code is anyway 'x86' specific (uses aes-ni) I could I guess simply decompile and implement for all possible variants of this.

However I don't really like this as a solution, and it feels a bit like guess programming. Further doing so doesn't really help me learn anything for any future such cases which may be a bit less specific to one architecture.

Is there a more generic/correct way to deal with this?
How do I go about telling the assembly that the variables are thread_local in a more generic way?
Or is there a way I can pass in the variables such that it doesn't need to know and works regardless?

Comment: If you implement it without inline assembly and compare the result with your own assembly you could perhaps find some hints. Is the inline assembly legacy code? If so, a new version of the compiler may optimize it enough so you can drop the inline assembly completely.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The assembly and reference versions are quite drastically different (and the assembly substantially faster) as the assembly takes advantage of vectorisation, aesenc and other instructions in a way that the compiler simply cannot.

I could in theory look at the assembly generated for a thread_local variable access in a small test case, but I suspect thats going to be different under different compilation conditions, while I'm looking for a more generic "correct way" to deal with this.

Comment: I see. The C++17 execution policy `parallel_unsequenced_policy` or C++20's `unsequenced_policy` could perhaps help to do some vectorization ... but if it'll be enough, I don't know.

Comment: Given that gcc has [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html) to directly access mmx/sse instructions (like __builtin_ia32_pxor), I would have expected you could get pretty close.  But it's true sometimes optimizers can do a very bad job.  Have you considered pure asm called w/parameters?  And since you are using gcc, why aren't you passing parameters using input/output [operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)? And you aren't really doing multiple asm statements like this, right?  The docs are pretty clear about that.

Comment: Note that while thread-local variables may make the code thread-safe, it is still not reentrant.  Your code looks like it is misusing gcc inline assembly (it seems that you assume registers keep their contents between `asm` statements) and there is likely a much better solution for what you want to do.

Comment: Are the routines huge/proprietary?  Or can you post one here so we can try to re-write it using extended asm or builtins?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd 

It is effectively this code here, (shavite3 hash function) https://github.com/floodyberry/supercop/blob/master/crypto_hash/shavite3256/aes-instruct/compress.h which is about 130 lines of asm instructions.

Yes I realise it is a somewhat obscure hash function, yes it does make sense to use it in the context it is used.

Comment: So, I re-wrote that supercop thing using intrinsics (all asm statements are gone).  However, the routine is long and complicated enough (and the conversion tedious enough) that I'm not very confident in the result.  I don't suppose you have a simple test routine I can use to validate?  Also, what hw capabilities are you targeting?  Can I assume SSE4.2?  AVX2?  Just rebuilding with AVX2 saves a bunch of instructions (all those 3 operand instructions make a difference), but I can't say whether it's any faster (or even correct) unless I can run it.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd 

I've put some basic [test vectors](https://pastebin.com/Kg3ic662) on pastebin.

Ideally I need to target whatever the machine is capable of using runtime CPU capability detection. So AVX2 on CPUs that have it, SSE2 on ones that don't. However if I can get just the basics working (assuming some base instruction set whatever you prefer). I can take it further from there for specific instruction sets as needed.

I don't expect others to do all the work for me, and your attempt at doing it with intrinsics at all is very kind, I wouldn't want to impose a specific set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer says, the inline asm is a mess and is misused. **Rewriting with intrinsics should be good**, and lets you compile with or without `-mavx` (or `-march=haswell` or `-march=znver1` or whatever) to let the compiler save a bunch of register-copy instructions.

Also it lets the compiler optimize (vector) register allocation and when to load/store, which is something compilers are pretty good at.

---

Ok, well, I wasn't able to use the test data you provided. It uses several other routines not provided here, and I'm too lazy to go looking for them.

That said, I was able to cobble something together for test data. And my E256() returns the same values as yours. That doesn't mean I've got it 100% correct (you'll want to do your own testing), but given all the xor/aesenc against everything over and over again, if something were wrong, I'd expect it to show.

**Converting to intrinsics wasn't particularly hard. Mostly you just need to find the equivalent `_mm_` function for the given asm instruction**. That and track down all places where you type x12 when you meant x13 (grrr).

Note that while this code makes use of variables named x0-x15, that's only because it made the translation easier. There is no correlation between these C variable names and the registers gcc will use when it compiles the code. Also, gcc uses a lot of knowledge about SSE to re-order instructions, so the output (esp for -O3) is very different from the original asm. If you're thinking you can compare them to check for correctness (like I did), expect to be frustrated.

This code contains both the original routines (prefixed with "old") and the new, and calls both from main() to see if they produce the same output. I have made no effort to make any changes to the builtins in an attempt to optimize it. As soon as it worked, I just stopped. I'll leave any further improvements to you, now that it's all C code.

That said, gcc is able to optimize intrinsics (something it can't do for asm). Which means that if you re-compile this code using `-mavx2`, the generated code is quite different.

Some stats:

- The original (fully expanded) code for E256() took up 287 instructions.
- Building with the intrinsics without -mavx2 takes 251.
- Building with the intrinsics with -mavx2 takes 196.

I haven't done any timings, but I like to believe that dropping ~100 lines of asm out will help. OTOH, sometimes gcc does a lousy job optimizing SSE, so don't assume anything.

Hope this helps.

```
// Compile with -O3 -msse4.2 -maes
//           or -O3 -msse4.2 -maes -mavx2
#include <wmmintrin.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

///////////////////////////
#define tos(a) #a
#define tostr(a) tos(a)

#define rev_reg_0321(j){ asm ("pshufb xmm" tostr(j)", [oldSHAVITE_REVERSE]"); }

#define replace_aes(i, j){ asm ("aesenc xmm" tostr(i)", xmm" tostr(j)""); }

__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int oldSHAVITE_MESS[16];
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned char oldSHAVITE_PTXT[8*4];
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int oldSHAVITE_CNTS[4] = {0,0,0,0};
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int oldSHAVITE_REVERSE[4] = {0x07060504, 0x0b0a0908, 0x0f0e0d0c, 0x03020100 };
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int oldSHAVITE256_XOR2[4] = {0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0, 0x0};
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int oldSHAVITE256_XOR3[4] = {0x0, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0};
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int oldSHAVITE256_XOR4[4] = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF};

#define oldmixing() do {\
    asm("movaps xmm11, xmm15");\
    asm("movaps xmm10, xmm14");\
    asm("movaps xmm9, xmm13");\
    asm("movaps xmm8, xmm12");\
\
    asm("movaps xmm6, xmm11");\
    asm("psrldq xmm6, 4");\
    asm("pxor xmm8, xmm6");\
    asm("movaps xmm6, xmm8");\
    asm("pslldq xmm6, 12");\
    asm("pxor xmm8, xmm6");\
\
    asm("movaps xmm7, xmm8");\
    asm("psrldq xmm7, 4");\
    asm("pxor xmm9, xmm7");\
    asm("movaps xmm7, xmm9");\
    asm("pslldq xmm7, 12");\
    asm("pxor xmm9, xmm7");\
\
    asm("movaps xmm6, xmm9");\
    asm("psrldq xmm6, 4");\
    asm("pxor xmm10, xmm6");\
    asm("movaps xmm6, xmm10");\
    asm("pslldq xmm6, 12");\
    asm("pxor xmm10, xmm6");\
\
    asm("movaps xmm7, xmm10");\
    asm("psrldq xmm7, 4");\
    asm("pxor xmm11, xmm7");\
    asm("movaps xmm7, xmm11");\
    asm("pslldq xmm7, 12");\
    asm("pxor xmm11, xmm7");\
} while(0);

void oldE256()
{
    asm (".intel_syntax noprefix");

    /* (L,R) = (xmm0,xmm1) */
    asm ("movaps xmm0, [oldSHAVITE_PTXT]");
    asm ("movaps xmm1, [oldSHAVITE_PTXT+16]");
    asm ("movaps xmm3, [oldSHAVITE_CNTS]");
    asm ("movaps xmm4, [oldSHAVITE256_XOR2]");
    asm ("pxor xmm2, xmm2");

    /* init key schedule */
    asm ("movaps xmm8, [oldSHAVITE_MESS]");
    asm ("movaps xmm9, [oldSHAVITE_MESS+16]");
    asm ("movaps xmm10, [oldSHAVITE_MESS+32]");
    asm ("movaps xmm11, [oldSHAVITE_MESS+48]");

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[0..15] */

    /* start key schedule */
    asm ("movaps xmm12, xmm8");
    asm ("movaps xmm13, xmm9");
    asm ("movaps xmm14, xmm10");
    asm ("movaps xmm15, xmm11");

    rev_reg_0321(12);
    rev_reg_0321(13);
    rev_reg_0321(14);
    rev_reg_0321(15);
    replace_aes(12, 2);
    replace_aes(13, 2);
    replace_aes(14, 2);
    replace_aes(15, 2);

    asm ("pxor xmm12, xmm3");
    asm ("pxor xmm12, xmm4");
    asm ("movaps xmm4, [oldSHAVITE256_XOR3]");
    asm ("pxor xmm12, xmm11");
    asm ("pxor xmm13, xmm12");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm13");
    asm ("pxor xmm15, xmm14");
    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[16..31] */

    /* F3 - first round */

    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm8");
    asm ("pxor xmm8, xmm1");
    replace_aes(8, 9);
    replace_aes(8, 10);
    replace_aes(8, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm0, xmm8");
    asm ("movaps xmm8, xmm6");

    /* F3 - second round */

    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm11");
    asm ("pxor xmm11, xmm0");
    replace_aes(11, 12);
    replace_aes(11, 13);
    replace_aes(11, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm1, xmm11");
    asm ("movaps xmm11, xmm6");

    /* key schedule */
    oldmixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 - rk[32..47] */

    /* F3 - third round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm14");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm1");
    replace_aes(14, 15);
    replace_aes(14, 8);
    replace_aes(14, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm0, xmm14");
    asm ("movaps xmm14, xmm6");

    /* key schedule */

    asm ("pshufd xmm3, xmm3,135");

    asm ("movaps xmm12, xmm8");
    asm ("movaps xmm13, xmm9");
    asm ("movaps xmm14, xmm10");
    asm ("movaps xmm15, xmm11");
    rev_reg_0321(12);
    rev_reg_0321(13);
    rev_reg_0321(14);
    rev_reg_0321(15);
    replace_aes(12, 2);
    replace_aes(13, 2);
    replace_aes(14, 2);
    replace_aes(15, 2);

    asm ("pxor xmm12, xmm11");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm3");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm4");
    asm ("movaps xmm4, [oldSHAVITE256_XOR4]");
    asm ("pxor xmm13, xmm12");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm13");
    asm ("pxor xmm15, xmm14");

    /* xmm12..xmm15 - rk[48..63] */

    /* F3 - fourth round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm9");
    asm ("pxor xmm9, xmm0");
    replace_aes(9, 10);
    replace_aes(9, 11);
    replace_aes(9, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm1, xmm9");
    asm ("movaps xmm9, xmm6");

    /* key schedule */
    oldmixing();
    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[64..79] */

    /* F3 - fifth round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm12");
    asm ("pxor xmm12, xmm1");
    replace_aes(12, 13);
    replace_aes(12, 14);
    replace_aes(12, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm0, xmm12");
    asm ("movaps xmm12, xmm6");

    /* F3 - sixth round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm15");
    asm ("pxor xmm15, xmm0");
    replace_aes(15, 8);
    replace_aes(15, 9);
    replace_aes(15, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm1, xmm15");
    asm ("movaps xmm15, xmm6");

    /* key schedule */
    asm ("pshufd xmm3, xmm3, 147");

    asm ("movaps xmm12, xmm8");
    asm ("movaps xmm13, xmm9");
    asm ("movaps xmm14, xmm10");
    asm ("movaps xmm15, xmm11");
    rev_reg_0321(12);
    rev_reg_0321(13);
    rev_reg_0321(14);
    rev_reg_0321(15);
    replace_aes(12, 2);
    replace_aes(13, 2);
    replace_aes(14, 2);
    replace_aes(15, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm12, xmm11");
    asm ("pxor xmm13, xmm3");
    asm ("pxor xmm13, xmm4");
    asm ("pxor xmm13, xmm12");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm13");
    asm ("pxor xmm15, xmm14");

    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[80..95] */

    /* F3 - seventh round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm10");
    asm ("pxor xmm10, xmm1");
    replace_aes(10, 11);
    replace_aes(10, 12);
    replace_aes(10, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm0, xmm10");
    asm ("movaps xmm10, xmm6");

    /* key schedule */
    oldmixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[96..111] */

    /* F3 - eigth round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm13");
    asm ("pxor xmm13, xmm0");
    replace_aes(13, 14);
    replace_aes(13, 15);
    replace_aes(13, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm1, xmm13");
    asm ("movaps xmm13, xmm6");

    /* key schedule */
    asm ("pshufd xmm3, xmm3, 135");

    asm ("movaps xmm12, xmm8");
    asm ("movaps xmm13, xmm9");
    asm ("movaps xmm14, xmm10");
    asm ("movaps xmm15, xmm11");
    rev_reg_0321(12);
    rev_reg_0321(13);
    rev_reg_0321(14);
    rev_reg_0321(15);
    replace_aes(12, 2);
    replace_aes(13, 2);
    replace_aes(14, 2);
    replace_aes(15, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm12, xmm11");
    asm ("pxor xmm15, xmm3");
    asm ("pxor xmm15, xmm4");
    asm ("pxor xmm13, xmm12");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm13");
    asm ("pxor xmm15, xmm14");

    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[112..127] */

    /* F3 - ninth round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm8");
    asm ("pxor xmm8, xmm1");
    replace_aes(8, 9);
    replace_aes(8, 10);
    replace_aes(8, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm0, xmm8");
    asm ("movaps xmm8, xmm6");
    /* F3 - tenth round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm11");
    asm ("pxor xmm11, xmm0");
    replace_aes(11, 12);
    replace_aes(11, 13);
    replace_aes(11, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm1, xmm11");
    asm ("movaps xmm11, xmm6");

    /* key schedule */
    oldmixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[128..143] */

    /* F3 - eleventh round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm14");
    asm ("pxor xmm14, xmm1");
    replace_aes(14, 15);
    replace_aes(14, 8);
    replace_aes(14, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm0, xmm14");
    asm ("movaps xmm14, xmm6");

    /* F3 - twelfth round */
    asm ("movaps xmm6, xmm9");
    asm ("pxor xmm9, xmm0");
    replace_aes(9, 10);
    replace_aes(9, 11);
    replace_aes(9, 2);
    asm ("pxor xmm1, xmm9");
    asm ("movaps xmm9, xmm6");

    /* feedforward */
    asm ("pxor xmm0, [oldSHAVITE_PTXT]");
    asm ("pxor xmm1, [oldSHAVITE_PTXT+16]");
    asm ("movaps [oldSHAVITE_PTXT], xmm0");
    asm ("movaps [oldSHAVITE_PTXT+16], xmm1");
    asm (".att_syntax noprefix");

    return;
}

void oldCompress256(const unsigned char *message_block, unsigned char *chaining_value, unsigned long long counter,
    const unsigned char salt[32])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=0;i<8*4;i++)
        oldSHAVITE_PTXT[i]=chaining_value[i];

     for (i=0;i<16;i++)
        oldSHAVITE_MESS[i] = *((unsigned int*)(message_block+4*i));

    oldSHAVITE_CNTS[0] = (unsigned int)(counter & 0xFFFFFFFFULL);
    oldSHAVITE_CNTS[1] = (unsigned int)(counter>>32);
    /* encryption + Davies-Meyer transform */
    oldE256();

    for (i=0; i<4*8; i++)
        chaining_value[i]=oldSHAVITE_PTXT[i];

     return;
}

////////////////////////////////

__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE_MESS[16];
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned char SHAVITE_PTXT[8*4];
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE_CNTS[4] = {0,0,0,0};
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE_REVERSE[4] = {0x07060504, 0x0b0a0908, 0x0f0e0d0c, 0x03020100 };
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE256_XOR2[4] = {0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0, 0x0};
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE256_XOR3[4] = {0x0, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0};
__attribute__ ((aligned (16))) unsigned int SHAVITE256_XOR4[4] = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF};

#define mixing() do {\
    x11 = x15; \
    x10 = x14; \
    x9 = x13;\
    x8 = x12;\
\
    x6 = x11;\
    x6 = _mm_srli_si128(x6, 4);\
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x6);\
    x6 = x8;\
    x6 = _mm_slli_si128(x6, 12);\
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x6);\
\
    x7 = x8;\
    x7 = _mm_srli_si128(x7, 4);\
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x7);\
    x7 = x9;\
    x7 = _mm_slli_si128(x7, 12);\
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x7);\
\
    x6 = x9;\
    x6 = _mm_srli_si128(x6, 4);\
    x10 = _mm_xor_si128(x10, x6);\
    x6 = x10;\
    x6 = _mm_slli_si128(x6, 12);\
    x10 = _mm_xor_si128(x10, x6);\
\
    x7 = x10;\
    x7 = _mm_srli_si128(x7, 4);\
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x7);\
    x7 = x11;\
    x7 = _mm_slli_si128(x7, 12);\
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x7);\
} while(0);

void E256()
{
    __m128i x0;
    __m128i x1;
    __m128i x2;
    __m128i x3;
    __m128i x4;
    __m128i x5;
    __m128i x6;
    __m128i x7;
    __m128i x8;
    __m128i x9;
    __m128i x10;
    __m128i x11;
    __m128i x12;
    __m128i x13;
    __m128i x14;
    __m128i x15;

    /* (L,R) = (xmm0,xmm1) */
    const __m128i ptxt1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)SHAVITE_PTXT);
    const __m128i ptxt2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(SHAVITE_PTXT+16));

    x0 = ptxt1;
    x1 = ptxt2;

    x3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)SHAVITE_CNTS);
    x4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)SHAVITE256_XOR2);
    x2 = _mm_setzero_si128();

    /* init key schedule */
    x8 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)SHAVITE_MESS);
    x9 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(SHAVITE_MESS+4));
    x10 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(SHAVITE_MESS+8));
    x11 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(SHAVITE_MESS+12));

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[0..15] */

    /* start key schedule */
    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;

const __m128i xtemp = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, xtemp);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, xtemp);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, xtemp);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, xtemp);

    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);

    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x3);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x4);
    x4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)SHAVITE256_XOR3);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);
    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[16..31] */

    /* F3 - first round */

    x6 = x8;
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x1);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x9);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x10);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x8);
    x8 = x6;

    /* F3 - second round */

    x6 = x11;
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x0);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x12);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x13);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x11);
    x11 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 - rk[32..47] */

    /* F3 - third round */
    x6 = x14;
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x1);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x15);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x8);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x14);
    x14 = x6;

    /* key schedule */

    x3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x3, 135);

    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;
    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, xtemp);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, xtemp);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, xtemp);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, xtemp);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);

    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x3);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x4);
    x4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)SHAVITE256_XOR4);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);

    /* xmm12..xmm15 - rk[48..63] */

    /* F3 - fourth round */
    x6 = x9;
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x0);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x10);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x11);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x9);
    x9 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();
    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[64..79] */

    /* F3 - fifth round */
    x6 = x12;
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x1);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x13);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x14);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x12);
    x12 = x6;

    /* F3 - sixth round */
    x6 = x15;
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x0);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x8);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x9);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x15);
    x15 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    x3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x3, 147);

    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;
    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, xtemp);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, xtemp);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, xtemp);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, xtemp);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x3);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x4);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);

    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[80..95] */

    /* F3 - seventh round */
    x6 = x10;
    x10 = _mm_xor_si128(x10, x1);
    x10 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x10, x11);
    x10 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x10, x12);
    x10 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x10, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x10);
    x10 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[96..111] */

    /* F3 - eigth round */
    x6 = x13;
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x0);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x14);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x15);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x13);
    x13 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    x3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x3, 135);

    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;
    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, xtemp);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, xtemp);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, xtemp);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, xtemp);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x3);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x4);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);

    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[112..127] */

    /* F3 - ninth round */
    x6 = x8;
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x1);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x9);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x10);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x8);
    x8 = x6;
    /* F3 - tenth round */
    x6 = x11;
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x0);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x12);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x13);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x11);
    x11 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[128..143] */

    /* F3 - eleventh round */
    x6 = x14;
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x1);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x15);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x8);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x14);
    x14 = x6;

    /* F3 - twelfth round */
    x6 = x9;
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x0);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x10);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x11);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x9);
    x9 = x6;

    /* feedforward */
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, ptxt1);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, ptxt2);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)SHAVITE_PTXT, x0);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)(SHAVITE_PTXT + 16), x1);

    return;
}

void Compress256(const unsigned char *message_block, unsigned char *chaining_value, unsigned long long counter,
    const unsigned char salt[32])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i=0;i<8*4;i++)
        SHAVITE_PTXT[i]=chaining_value[i];

    for (i=0;i<16;i++)
        SHAVITE_MESS[i] = *((unsigned int*)(message_block+4*i));

    SHAVITE_CNTS[0] = (unsigned int)(counter & 0xFFFFFFFFULL);
    SHAVITE_CNTS[1] = (unsigned int)(counter>>32);
    /* encryption + Davies-Meyer transform */
    E256();

    for (i=0; i<4*8; i++)
        chaining_value[i]=SHAVITE_PTXT[i];

     return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int cvlen = 32;
    unsigned char *cv = (unsigned char *)malloc(cvlen);

    for (int x=0; x < cvlen; x++)
        cv[x] = x + argc;

    const int mblen = 64;
    unsigned char *mb = (unsigned char *)malloc(mblen);

    for (int x=0; x < mblen; x++)
        mb[x] = x + argc;

    unsigned long long counter = 0x1234567812345678ull;

    unsigned char s[32] = {0};
    oldCompress256(mb, cv, counter, s);

    printf("old: ");
    for (int x=0; x < cvlen; x++)
        printf("%2x ", cv[x]);
    printf("\n");

    for (int x=0; x < cvlen; x++)
        cv[x] = x + argc;

    Compress256(mb, cv, counter, s);

    printf("new: ");
    for (int x=0; x < cvlen; x++)
        printf("%2x ", cv[x]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

Edit:

The globals are only used to pass values between C and asm. Perhaps the asm writer didn't know how to access parameters? IAC, they're unnecessary (and the source of the thread safety issues). Here's the code without them (along with some cosmetic changes):

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define mixing() \
    x11 = x15;\
    x10 = x14;\
    x9 = x13;\
    x8 = x12;\
\
    x6 = x11;\
    x6 = _mm_srli_si128(x6, 4);\
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x6);\
    x6 = x8;\
    x6 = _mm_slli_si128(x6, 12);\
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x6);\
\
    x7 = x8;\
    x7 = _mm_srli_si128(x7, 4);\
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x7);\
    x7 = x9;\
    x7 = _mm_slli_si128(x7, 12);\
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x7);\
\
    x6 = x9;\
    x6 = _mm_srli_si128(x6, 4);\
    x10 = _mm_xor_si128(x10, x6);\
    x6 = x10;\
    x6 = _mm_slli_si128(x6, 12);\
    x10 = _mm_xor_si128(x10, x6);\
\
    x7 = x10;\
    x7 = _mm_srli_si128(x7, 4);\
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x7);\
    x7 = x11;\
    x7 = _mm_slli_si128(x7, 12);\
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x7);

// If mess & chain won't be 16byte aligned, change _mm_load to _mm_loadu and
// _mm_store to _mm_storeu
void Compress256(const __m128i *mess, __m128i *chain, unsigned long long counter, const unsigned char salt[32])
{
    // note: _mm_set_epi32 uses (int e3, int e2, int e1, int e0)
    const __m128i SHAVITE_REVERSE = _mm_set_epi32(0x03020100, 0x0f0e0d0c, 0x0b0a0908, 0x07060504);
    const __m128i SHAVITE256_XOR2 = _mm_set_epi32(0x0, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0);
    const __m128i SHAVITE256_XOR3 = _mm_set_epi32(0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0, 0x0);
    const __m128i SHAVITE256_XOR4 = _mm_set_epi32(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
    const __m128i SHAVITE_CNTS =
        _mm_set_epi32(0, 0, (unsigned int)(counter>>32), (unsigned int)(counter & 0xFFFFFFFFULL));

    __m128i x0, x1, x2, x3, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15;

    /* (L,R) = (xmm0,xmm1) */
    const __m128i ptxt1 = _mm_load_si128(chain);
    const __m128i ptxt2 = _mm_load_si128(chain+1);

    x0 = ptxt1;
    x1 = ptxt2;

    x3 = SHAVITE_CNTS;
    x2 = _mm_setzero_si128();

    /* init key schedule */
    x8 = _mm_load_si128(mess);
    x9 = _mm_load_si128(mess+1);
    x10 = _mm_load_si128(mess+2);
    x11 = _mm_load_si128(mess+3);

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[0..15] */

    /* start key schedule */
    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;

    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, SHAVITE_REVERSE);

    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);

    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x3);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, SHAVITE256_XOR2);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);

    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[16..31] */

    /* F3 - first round */
    x6 = x8;
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x1);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x9);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x10);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x8);
    x8 = x6;

    /* F3 - second round */
    x6 = x11;
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x0);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x12);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x13);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x11);
    x11 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 - rk[32..47] */

    /* F3 - third round */
    x6 = x14;
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x1);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x15);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x8);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x14);
    x14 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    x3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x3, 135);

    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;
    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);

    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x3);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, SHAVITE256_XOR3);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);

    /* xmm12..xmm15 - rk[48..63] */

    /* F3 - fourth round */
    x6 = x9;
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x0);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x10);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x11);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x9);
    x9 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[64..79] */

    /* F3 - fifth round */
    x6 = x12;
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x1);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x13);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x14);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x12);
    x12 = x6;

    /* F3 - sixth round */
    x6 = x15;
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x0);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x8);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x9);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x15);
    x15 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    x3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x3, 147);

    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;
    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x3);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, SHAVITE256_XOR4);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);

    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[80..95] */

    /* F3 - seventh round */
    x6 = x10;
    x10 = _mm_xor_si128(x10, x1);
    x10 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x10, x11);
    x10 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x10, x12);
    x10 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x10, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x10);
    x10 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[96..111] */

    /* F3 - eigth round */
    x6 = x13;
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x0);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x14);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x15);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x13);
    x13 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    x3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x3, 135);

    x12 = x8;
    x13 = x9;
    x14 = x10;
    x15 = x11;
    x12 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x12, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x13 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x13, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x14 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x14, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x15 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x15, SHAVITE_REVERSE);
    x12 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x12, x2);
    x13 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x13, x2);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x15 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x15, x2);
    x12 = _mm_xor_si128(x12, x11);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x3);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, SHAVITE256_XOR4);
    x13 = _mm_xor_si128(x13, x12);
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x13);
    x15 = _mm_xor_si128(x15, x14);

    /* xmm12..xmm15 = rk[112..127] */

    /* F3 - ninth round */
    x6 = x8;
    x8 = _mm_xor_si128(x8, x1);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x9);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x10);
    x8 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x8, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x8);
    x8 = x6;

    /* F3 - tenth round */
    x6 = x11;
    x11 = _mm_xor_si128(x11, x0);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x12);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x13);
    x11 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x11, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x11);
    x11 = x6;

    /* key schedule */
    mixing();

    /* xmm8..xmm11 = rk[128..143] */

    /* F3 - eleventh round */
    x6 = x14;
    x14 = _mm_xor_si128(x14, x1);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x15);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x8);
    x14 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x14, x2);
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, x14);
    x14 = x6;

    /* F3 - twelfth round */
    x6 = x9;
    x9 = _mm_xor_si128(x9, x0);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x10);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x11);
    x9 = _mm_aesenc_si128(x9, x2);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, x9);
    x9 = x6;

    /* feedforward */
    x0 = _mm_xor_si128(x0, ptxt1);
    x1 = _mm_xor_si128(x1, ptxt2);
    _mm_store_si128(chain, x0);
    _mm_store_si128(chain + 1, x1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    __m128i chain[2], mess[4];
    unsigned char *p;

    // argc prevents compiler from precalculating results

    p = (unsigned char *)mess;
    for (int x=0; x < 64; x++)
        p[x] = x + argc;

    p = (unsigned char *)chain;
    for (int x=0; x < 32; x++)
        p[x] = x + argc;

    unsigned long long counter = 0x1234567812345678ull + argc;

    // Unused, but prototype requires it.
    unsigned char s[32] = {0};

    Compress256(mess, chain, counter, s);

    for (int x=0; x < 32; x++)
        printf("%02x ", p[x]);
    printf("\n");

    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    unsigned char res = 0;

    for (int x=0; x < 400000; x++)
    {
        Compress256(mess, chain, counter, s);

        // Ensure optimizer doesn't omit the calc
        res ^= *p;
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

    unsigned long long delta_us = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000ull + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000ull;
    printf("%x: %llu\n", res, delta_us);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, intrinsics are great to let you take advantage of AVX to avoid `movdqa` register-copy instructions, and use unaligned memory source operands.  Since you're only using 128-bit integer vectors, you only need `-mavx` to get this benefit.  (In other cases AVX2 `vpblendd` can be useful to the compiler when optimizing 128-bit intrinsics, but probably not here.)  If you want to tell the optimizer to tune for a newer CPU, you need `-mtune=haswell` or `-mtune=znver1`; `-mavx2` unfortunately *doesn't* make it stop caring about Sandybridge, Core 2 or Phenom II.

Comment: Can confirm that this works correctly, great job!

Benchmarks are showing a ~6% gain over the asm code with (O3, ssse3, aes) and saturating all cores with function calls.

Increasing to sse4.2 or avx2 appears to give slight gains above this but not substantial, this is not that unexpected as the aes calls are likely taking up the bulk of execution time. I'll play a bit more with it though.

I'm not 100% sure which answer I should select the answer from @PeterCordes better answers the original assembly question, while this one better solves my actual problem, both are good details answers

Comment: @MalcolmMacLeod: I added a brief intro to this answer to make it directly answer the question and introduce the fact that it's about *how* to convert to intrinsics.  IMO you should accept this one, because if people are using inline asm properly in the first place (`"m"` operands) they won't need my answer; it will already just work.

Comment: It looks like those global declarations (SHAVITE*) may only be used to pass values into the asm.  Perhaps the author wasn't sure how to access function parameters or local variables from asm?  Now that it's C, moving SHAVITE_REVERSE and SHAVITE_XOR* inside E256() as const locals, and passing the values in Compress256 as parameters (ie skipping the redundant memcpy back and forth to the globals) looks to eke out a bit more performance.  And (I expect) also relieves your original thread safety issues.  Assuming you haven't already done this...

Comment: @DavidWohlferd 

Yes you are right, I had assumed at first that at least some of them stored state across calls but it appears that is not the case. 

The Compress256  function that calls E256 can be removed entirely in fact along with the removal of the global variables, both are completely unnecessary...
I've done that this side, the performance gains are seemingly not much but the code is clearer for it anyway.

Comment: Huh. Faster for me, but maybe your "write to global" gets folded into the routines you use to build the message. At one point I accidentally compiled with x86 (only 8 xmm registers vs 16), and the perf was unchanged. Like you said, the aesenc seems to dominate.  Still, cleaner is better, and (I assume) your thread issue is d-e-d. I'm going to update this with my "final" code. It sounds like yours is functionally identical, so probably no point in changing it.  But I want to have it here for future SO users.  I mean, who knows how many Shavite Compression users there are in the world, right?

Comment: Or not.  Seems I've maxed out the length of an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If your current code is using a separate "basic" asm statement for each instruction, it's badly written and lies to the compiler by clobbering XMM registers without telling it.  **That's not how you use GNU C inline asm.**

You should rewrite it with [AES-NI and SIMD intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,Other&expand=6150,620,4968,4202,5657,5609&text=aes) like `_mm_aesdec_si128` so the compiler will emit the right addressing modes for everything.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

---

Or if you really want to still use GNU C inline asm, **use [Extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) with input/output `"+m"` operands**, which can be local vars or whatever C variable you want, including static or thread-local.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for links to guides about inlien asm.

But hopefully you can just make them automatic storage inside your function, or have the caller allocate and pass a pointer to context instead of using static or thread-local storage at all.  Thread-local is slightly slower to access because the non-zero segment base slows down address calculation in the load execution unit.  Probably not much of an issue when the address is ready plenty early, I think, but make sure you actually need TLS instead of just scratch space on the stack or provided by the caller.  It also hurts code-size.

**When GCC fills in a `%0` or `%[named]` operand in the template for an `"m"` operand constraint, it uses the appropriate addressing mode.**  Whether that's `fs:SHAVITE_PTXT@tpoff+16` or `XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]` or `XMMWORD PTR _ZZ3foovE15SHAVITE256_XOR2[rip]` (for a function-local static variable), it just works.  (As long as you don't run into operand-size mismatches with Intel-syntax, where the compiler fills that in with the memory operand, instead of leaving it to the mnemonic suffix like with AT&T syntax mode.)

Like this, using global, TLS-global, local automatic, and local static variables just to demonstrate that they all work the same.

```
// compile with -masm=intel

//#include <stdalign.h>  // for C11
alignas(16) unsigned int SHAVITE_MESS[16];                 // global (static storage)
alignas(16) thread_local unsigned char SHAVITE_PTXT[8*4];  // TLS global

void foo() {
    alignas(16) unsigned int SHAVITE_CNTS[4] = {0,0,0,0};   // automatic storage (initialized)
    alignas(16) static unsigned int SHAVITE256_XOR2[4];     // local static

    asm (
        "movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr %[PTXT]     \n\t"
        "movaps xmm1, xmmword ptr %[PTXT]+16  \n\t"   // x86 addressing modes are always offsetable
        "pxor   xmm2,  xmm2       \n\t"          // mix shorter insns with longer insns to help decode and uop-cache packing
        "movaps xmm3, xmmword ptr %[CNTS]+0     \n\t"
        "movaps xmm4, xmmword ptr %[XOR2_256]"

       : [CNTS] "+m" (SHAVITE_CNTS),    // outputs and read/write operands
         [PTXT] "+m" (SHAVITE_PTXT),
         [XOR2_256] "+m" (SHAVITE256_XOR2)

       : [MESS] "m" (SHAVITE_MESS)      // read-only inputs

       : "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4"  // clobbers: list all you use
    );
}
```

You can make it portable between 32 and 64-bit mode if you avoid xmm8..15, or protect that with `#ifdef __x86_64__`

Note that `[PTXT] "+m" (SHAVITE_PTXT)` as an operand means the entire array is an input/output, when `SHAVITE_PTXT` is a true array, *not* a `char*`.

It expands to an addressing mode for the start of the object of course, but you can offset this with a constant like `+16`.  The assembler accepts `[rsp-24]+16` as equivalent to `[rsp-8]` so it Just Works for base-register or static addresses.

Telling the compiler that the whole array in an input and/or output means it can safely optimize around the asm statement even after inlining.  e.g.  the compiler knows that writes to higher array elements are also relevant for the input / output of the asm, not just the first byte.  It can't keep later elements in registers across the asm, or reorder loads/stores to those arrays.

---

If you had used `SHAVITE_PTXT[0]` (which would work even with a pointer), the compiler will in the operand as Intel-syntax `byte ptr foobar`.  But fortunately, with `xmmword ptr byte ptr` the first one takes precedence and matches the operand-size for `movaps`xmm0, xmmword ptr %[foo]`.  (You don't have this problem with AT&T syntax where the mnemonic carries the operand-size via a suffix if necessary; the compiler doesn't fill in anything.)

Some of your arrays happen to be 16 bytes in size so the compiler already fills in `xmmword ptr`, but redundancy there is fine, too.

If you just have pointers instead of arrays, see [How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432259/how-can-i-indicate-that-the-memory-pointed-to-by-an-inline-asm-argument-may-be) for the `"m" (*(unsigned (*)[16]) SHAVITE_MESS)` syntax.  You can use this as your real input operand, or as a "dummy" input alongside a pointer in a `"+r"` operand.

Or perhaps better, **ask for a SIMD register** input, output, or read/write operand like `[PTXT16] "+x"( *(__m128i)&array[16] )`.  It can pick any XMM register you didn't declare a clobber on.  Use `#include <immintrin.h>` to define `__m128i`, or do it yourself with GNU C native vector syntax.  `__m128i` uses `__attribute__((may_alias))` so that pointer-casting doesn't create strict-aliasing UB.

This is especially good if the compiler can inline this and keep a local variable in an XMM register across asm statements, instead of your hand-written asm doing a store/reload keeping things in memory.

---

#### compiler *output* for the above source:

From [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//%23include+%3Cstdalign.h%3E++//+for+C11%0Aalignas(16)+unsigned+int+SHAVITE_MESS%5B16%5D%3B+++++++++++++++++//+global+(static+storage)%0Aalignas(16)+thread_local+unsigned+char+SHAVITE_PTXT%5B8*4%5D%3B++//+TLS+global%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++alignas(16)+unsigned+int+SHAVITE_CNTS%5B4%5D+%3D+%7B0,0,0,0%7D%3B+++//+automatic+storage+(initialized)%0A++++alignas(16)+static+unsigned+int+SHAVITE256_XOR2%5B4%5D%3B+++++//+local+static%0A%0A++++asm+(%0A++++++++%22movaps+xmm0,+xmmword+ptr+%25%5BPTXT%5D+++++%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A++++++++%22movaps+xmm1,+xmmword+ptr+%25%5BPTXT%5D%2B16++%5Cn%5Ct%22+++//+x86+addressing+modes+are+always+offsetable%0A++++++++%22pxor+++xmm2,++xmm2+++++++%5Cn%5Ct%22+++//+mix+shorter+insns+with+longer+insns+to+help+decode+and+uop-cache+packing%0A++++++++%22movaps+xmm3,+xmmword+ptr+%25%5BCNTS%5D%2B0+++++%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A++++++++%22movaps+xmm4,+xmmword+ptr+%25%5BXOR2_256%5D%22%0A%0A+++++++:+%5BCNTS%5D+%22%2Bm%22+(SHAVITE_CNTS),++++//+outputs+and+read/write+operands%0A+++++++++%5BPTXT%5D+%22%2Bm%22+(SHAVITE_PTXT),%0A+++++++++%5BXOR2_256%5D+%22%2Bm%22+(SHAVITE256_XOR2)%0A%0A+++++++:+%5BMESS%5D+%22m%22+(SHAVITE_MESS)++++++//+read-only+inputs%0A%0A+++++++:+%22xmm0%22,+%22xmm1%22,+%22xmm2%22,+%22xmm3%22,+%22xmm4%22++//+clobbers:+list+all+you+use%0A++++)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.12192114568755,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-masm%3Dintel',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:47.87807885431246,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-masm%3Dintel',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.87807885431246,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) with gcc9.2.  This is just the compiler's asm text output after filling in the `%[stuff]` in the template.

```
# g++ -O3 -masm=intel
foo():
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24], xmm0      # compiler-generated zero-init array

        movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr fs:SHAVITE_PTXT@tpoff     
        movaps xmm1, xmmword ptr fs:SHAVITE_PTXT@tpoff+16  
        pxor   xmm2,  xmm2       
        movaps xmm3, xmmword ptr XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]+0     
        movaps xmm4, xmmword ptr XMMWORD PTR foo()::SHAVITE256_XOR2[rip]
        ret
```

And this is the disassembly of the assembled binary output:

```
foo():
 pxor   xmm0,xmm0
 movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp-0x18],xmm0   # compiler-generated

 movaps xmm0,XMMWORD PTR fs:0xffffffffffffffe0
 movaps xmm1,XMMWORD PTR fs:0xfffffffffffffff0    # note the +16 worked
 pxor   xmm2,xmm2
 movaps xmm3,XMMWORD PTR [rsp-0x18]               # note the +0 assembled without syntax error
 movaps xmm4,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x200ae5]        # 601080 <foo()::SHAVITE256_XOR2>
 ret
```

Also note that the non-TLS global variable used a RIP-relative addressing mode but the TLS one didn't, using a sign-extended `[disp32]` absolute addressing mode.

(In position-*dependent* code, you can in theory use a RIP-relative addressing mode to generate a small absolute address like that relative to the TLS base.  I don't think GCC does that, though.)

Comment: Ok, I'll bite: Why no mention of the `"v"` [constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html)?  Obviously it won't work for arrays or offsets, but if you're listing all the ways to access xmms, it seems like it should be on the list.  And I'd expect it to handle thread variables just fine.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Unless you're assuming AVX512VL, best to use `"x"` if you want data in a vector register so you don't get `xmm16..31` in 64-bit mode.  But yes, a `"+x"( *(__m128i)&array[16] )` operand would work.  I assumed the OP wanted to do all their own loads/stores in inline asm and leave data in memory or use it as scratch space.  But yes, since I mentioned locals, I should probably mention getting the compiler to take inputs / outputs in XMM regs.

Comment: Ahh, I knew there'd be a reason.  Can't learn if I don't ask.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: That was a good suggestion though; I did add a paragraph about using an `"x"` constraint since I had overlooked that.  Using clobbers makes it safe to still use *some* hard-coded registers.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful, and you are right a local (user passed in context) would be much better than a global.