# gcc inline-assembly compilation error when optimization flags is not enabled?

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I've been studying inline-assembly for almost 1 month now, and as another practice problem, I'm trying to add up two `uint512` using inline-assembly, at first I got what I wanted, the code compiles and I was able to get the correct result with my code below. Though until this time I'm only compiling my program with optimization flags; -O2 and -O3.

But when I tried to remove -O1, -O2 or -O3 in my compilation flag it produces a compilation error `error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints`   , **what could be the reason for this?**

I'm assuming because the optimizations is disabled, the program is actually trying to use more registers than my CPU have?. Still I'm just using 8 registers (or maybe not anymore?), is my input being stored in another 8 registers instead?

```cpp
// uint512 += uint512
void uint512_add(unsigned long *sum, unsigned long *add) {
    asm volatile(
        "add %[adn0], %[sum0]\n\t"
        "adc %[adn1], %[sum1]\n\t"
        "adc %[adn2], %[sum2]\n\t"
        "adc %[adn3], %[sum3]\n\t"
        "adc %[adn4], %[sum4]\n\t"
        "adc %[adn5], %[sum5]\n\t"
        "adc %[adn6], %[sum6]\n\t"
        "adc %[adn7], %[sum7]"
        :
        [sum0]"+r"(sum[0]), [sum1]"+r"(sum[1]),
        [sum2]"+r"(sum[2]), [sum3]"+r"(sum[3]),
        [sum4]"+r"(sum[4]), [sum5]"+r"(sum[5]),
        [sum6]"+r"(sum[6]), [sum7]"+r"(sum[7])
        :
        [adn0]"m"(add[0]), [adn1]"m"(add[1]),
        [adn2]"m"(add[2]), [adn3]"m"(add[3]),
        [adn4]"m"(add[4]), [adn5]"m"(add[5]),
        [adn6]"m"(add[6]), [adn7]"m"(add[7])
        : "memory", "cc"
    );
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of part of [Strange 'asm' operand has impossible constraints error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46016819) , but that's not a good canonical answer because the question has other bugs.  Or [Inline asm fails to compile without optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63023087) but that's not multiple offsets from one base, it's dummy memory operands that match up with separate pointer inputs.

Comment: This is an instance where getting the compiler to do all your loads and stores may not be a win.  If you do it by hand within the asm, reusing the same architectural register for each iteration, you should only need a couple of registers all told,  and I would suspect it won't be noticeably slower.  That will then reduce register pressure on the surrounding code, and also save you the overhead of pushing and popping all the call-preserved registers that the current version would need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove some of the operands, like for just a 256-bit add, you'll notice that **with optimization disabled, GCC wants to put a pointer directly to each memory operand in a separate register**, instead of inventing addressing modes for each of them relative to the same base. So it runs out of registers.  (See the middle part of [Strange 'asm' operand has impossible constraints error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46016819) for compiler output that demos this.)

You might want `__attribute__((optimize("-O3")))` on this function or something so it doesn't stop the rest of your program from compiling.

---

Also, this doesn't need a "memory" clobber; you don't write any memory, and you only read via `"m"` operands. It also doesn't need to be volatile: it has no side effects besides writing the `"+r"` in/output regs.  Except for `sum7`, technically those should be `"+&r"` early-clobber operands, since you write them before reading all of the input and in-out operands, but there's basically no plausible way for GCC to overlap registers between pointers and integer in/out here.

You could also let the compiler choose `"mre"` instead of forcing memory source operands even if the source operand was a compile-time constant or in a register.  But if that makes it generate worse asm for your actual use-case (e.g. separate `mov` load into regs instead of memory source for `adc`), then maybe just `"me"`.  (The [`"e"` constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) is like `"i"` but only allowing constants that fit in a 32-bit signed integer, i.e. safe for use as an immediate with 64-bit operand-size for instructions other than `mov`.)

---

BTW, with clang (but not GCC) you don't need inline asm at all: use `typedef unsigned _ExtInt(512) uint512;` - see [256-bit arithmetic in Clang (extended integers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226753/256-bit-arithmetic-in-clang-extended-integers)