# RISC-V inline assembly using memory not behaving correctly

Tags: inline-assembly, riscv

This system call code is not working at all. The compiler is optimizing things out and generally behaving strangely:

```
template <typename... Args>
inline void print(Args&&... args)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    auto res = strf::to(buffer) (std::forward<Args> (args)...);
    const size_t size = res.ptr - buffer;

    register const char* a0 asm("a0") = buffer;
    register size_t      a1 asm("a1") = size;
    register long syscall_id asm("a7") = ECALL_WRITE;
    register long        a0_out asm("a0");

    asm volatile ("ecall" : "=r"(a0_out)
        : "m"(*(const char(*)[size]) a0), "r"(a1), "r"(syscall_id) : "memory");
}
```

This is a custom system call that takes a buffer and a length as arguments.
If I write this using global assembly it works as expected, but program code has generally been extraordinarily good if I write the wrappers inline.

A function that calls the print function with a constant string produces invalid machine code:

```
0000000000120f54 <start>:
start():
  120f54:       fa1ff06f                j       120ef4 <public_donothing-0x5c>
-->
  120ef4:       747367b7                lui     a5,0x74736
  120ef8:       c0010113                addi    sp,sp,-1024
  120efc:       55478793                addi    a5,a5,1364 # 74736554 <add_work+0x74615310>
  120f00:       00f12023                sw      a5,0(sp)
  120f04:       00a00793                li      a5,10
  120f08:       00f10223                sb      a5,4(sp)
  120f0c:       000102a3                sb      zero,5(sp)
  120f10:       00500593                li      a1,5
  120f14:       06600893                li      a7,102
  120f18:       00000073                ecall
  120f1c:       40010113                addi    sp,sp,1024
  120f20:       00008067                ret
```

It's not loading a0 with the buffer at sp.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It's not loading a0 with the buffer at sp.*

Because you didn't ask for a pointer as an `"r"` input in a register.  The one and only [guaranteed/supported behaviour](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) of `T foo asm("a0")` is to make an **`"r"`** constraint (including +r or =r) pick that register.

But you used `"m"` to let it pick an addressing mode for that buffer, not necessarily `0(a0)`, so it probably picked an SP-relative mode.  If you add asm comments inside the template like `"ecall  # 0 = %0   1 = %1  2 = %2"` you can look at the compiler's asm output and see what it picked.  (With clang, use `-no-integrated-as` so asm comments in the template come through in the `-S` output.)

Wrapping a system call does need the pointer in a specific register, i.e. using `"r"` or `+"r"`

```
    asm volatile ("ecall  # 0=%0   1=%1  2=%2  3=%3  4=%4"
        : "=r"(a0_out)
        : "r"(a0), "r"(a1), "r"(syscall_id), "m"(*(const char(*)[size]) a0)
        : // "memory"  unneeded; the "m" input tells the compiler which memory is read
    );
```

**That `"m"` input can be used [instead of the `"memory"` clobber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432259/how-can-i-indicate-that-the-memory-pointed-to-by-an-inline-asm-argument-may-be), not instead of an `"r"` pointer input**.  (For `write` specifically, because it only reads that one area of pointed-to memory and has no other side-effects on memory user-space can see, only on kernel write write buffers and file-descriptor positions which aren't C objects this program can access directly.  For a `read` call, you'd need the memory to be an output operand.)

With optimization disabled, compilers do typically pick another register as the base for the `"m"` input (e.g. `0(a5)` for GCC), but with optimization enabled GCC picks `0(a0)` so it doesn't cost extra instructions.  Clang still picks `0(a2)`, wasting an instruction to set up that pointer, even though the `"=r"(a0_out)` is not early-clobber.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCCSAKykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0bEJCnUNTdmtQ109xaUDAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuQ/iCAHQIB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHx7R4EeeX1zcA9D/3DG2Xj2BzcTAULB%2BXgYeGOn3W2F2%2BzMm0Bj2eRwAngofgpsaJaLR4VdbhssDQQrtsG4bgEAgB9ADqACUAJIAFURXBRkm%2B3z%2BBEwLESBkFGIImMSjFYmFOct2N2IwAUX1uf2Cb0pADdUHh0LtEsRggQIIrleYAGyWuWnXb1ZWzb60ATAA1GwT0iJeYDATEQNAMIa7ZAIeq7ABU/FQjtJAHYrLckUiQ2GvVQqNETHELFwNGZeXEACIHBM3JO7P5MLxEXbETAKZ6F3ZDYhUEAgIgQNMZ4izXYQY7t/jEADu9XQoLNKoR/ftClmNsd61L5b%2BAaDqQAXph6QRm3ht43a/XTokCMRdgBaXbdzPL77lrc7vdPo9mEtIv4GgwrBCeLAXsO%2B7CvQdoQg%2BSa3sQWYWBoWZNgcTZRjBcFFiWfKJkmdbALCgoXuue4psQ4Z2hoYEsBA5hmEwcFmGYfaITeXjpneK5YZgOFDNE%2B7bru5ZIkwXDkZRdGCVRDHrE2T7oZhSLYbh3HOkYzb4mItD0nqwlUUwsbiUe1K0gyLIclc96ycenF4bsSmuvxAkaPSix7uCFHabR9EyXc5kubsOqinQTwiWYmAErQSIbLsZGMeYcRkUiQnRWYcRCbsZhHjF750bsIDIu%2BknQXREA0Y51YxmWdnZblLBURA4b%2BgIQZEbVjrZtJRZ9jR8y5QVZhFVwXVUT1A6qYSGnoH2OVUWwLAkJi4meeWdYEEsDCkSVBCeSYsbFqSu03DZbrGvSNCqJg6D1YGhGhhekaoNGfLxhBybXUxLHQdmub5vBC1JpW1aoMeDaMS2bYdqgXbMT2fYDgQ6BDiQY7EBOhxTpcs5KvOi4/Z%2BPwETxz740edYKKe55Xq9PbY/jfGvoxeUWDj35ML%2B/7cUBqQgU8LlPRTmbZqhCGSbsyH899ZleeVckcQp%2BENVd9QkTRWmie5ElNlBVPyVxF5Pnx/GCcr1FcHpwMHpgmvS9r1kuipCihWNhs6SbQsGXSTJspyFuWYpNsVcVTmO6rm3eRCvmeEwjigUFIVqeFKKRYhMVxbsxuSTFKV5cWSVpbs6yJ0l6xIryadJbydE8%2BWk3l/lNX%2B6VFdJlXZhDZ1pDdbX/Vt4NNV4nbaljQNdHVYVdV4014YtRYbWFh1GhlRVlVflNQqzVRSLQiEZ1nR%2BBAIE8U1r8EiTVrsgqEg2u9PGgwoBReI4IHgIa7NNs27LCx5MBO5lLmxUvLcQq064bXFltHaNwODzFoJwOIvA/AcC0KQVAnA3DWGsM2RYyx94oh4KQAgmgIHzAANYgHWOsU4ABOWMAAOKhcR1g0LiHEMwVD8wJCgRwSQvAWASA0BoUgcCEFII4LwBQIA%2BF4PgRA0gcBYBIGvokW%2B5BKDyNviAYgWp1hmEvNsQwwAuDrA0K0GgtA8KiK7Pg0gERgj1ExJwHB182CCAAPIMFoLYyRpAsAsF0eIDx%2BA6wODwFqesFjMCnWQNWVYODjSVAsW8CIxAbEeCwBY88eBuHcCkVQAwyoABqeBMAjicVKOBOD%2BCCBEGIdgUgZCCEUCodQHjdCtAMEYFAqDLD6HeKIyA8xUBnnSKIjgl4nGF0vFQYJxAIgpEwJeHyl4GCoEvDE4AiTBToDmQoERlQQrVBcAwdwnhmj%2BAOVMPoMRWi5DSAIUYLQkgpGuQwM5JR%2BjjB2YEgQnQRhHLGG0XZHRhjdGCL0F5FzbCAtuXoCYDRnkzE7goDBKw9DnkwFEqR7CYH8IsUItkQg3CXlybWDRZhgDIGDK010%2BjTgaFOEJCAKDLDWDbrgQgJBkTrFaLsDwN96AXg2P1XgEitCzCISQswpwLRUOodyaV%2BiqGSGkOwzhWKPFCJEWI3B%2BD5gyMQCgVAPLohKPqgamI6jNGXlJcgT6fDjGmMoBECxVjmDEHcfY/VjiCAuLcRYrxPjVgIP8f84JQyEFhJCpEuxvAYnsIQfExJLrkn%2BsFUaDJPB5jZKYHkgpRSSmRtqcIAk1TpDlPkEoNQFjdBmH0Lo9pjLOnxJ6RAPpAyGqcBGWlcZkzplKE2SwbZ7RnAQFcJC1ogRgXTFefcvI6QR1TsebCyddh/mfIhT8u5S6Pk1EBQusF0LGhrqhdu8d5yJDzARUsJFrQUVosgdA2B2LOC4vxYSs1JKyWWpTjS8VZF6UdJsFSfARA%2BXYLbtyhRvL2X0UFVq0VpDTikIQ4hpD%2BhODKoEbwNVtgNVCoIShjgZguE8L4ehxBnBoOSJFaQSZqRnCSCAA%3D%3D%3D), with a very cut-down version of the function that doesn't call `strf::to`, whatever that is, just copies a byte into the buffer.)

---

Interestingly, with optimization enabled for my cut-down stand-alone version of the function without fixing the bug, GCC and clang *do* happen to put a pointer to `buffer` into `a0`, picking `0(a0)` as the template expansion for that operand (see the Godbolt link above).  This seems to be a missed optimization vs. using `16(sp)`; I don't see why they'd need the buffer address in a register at all.

But without optimization, GCC picks `ecall  # 0 = a0   1 = 0(a5)  2 = a1`.  (In my simplified version of the function, it sets a5 with `mv a5,a0`, so it did actually have the address in a0 as well.  So it's a good thing you had more code in your function to make it not happen to work by accident, so you could find the bug in your code.)

Comment: Thank you so much. That's a heroic reply if I've ever seen one!