# How to use _mm256_shuffle_epi8 to order elements

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx

I try following code. I know there are some lane restrictions in the shuffle function. But I don't know how to handle it properly. Has someone an idea?

```
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
  auto vals = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0, 3, 6, 9,
    1, 4, 7, 10,
    2, 5, 8, 11,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    12, 15, 18, 21,
    13, 16, 19, 22,
    14, 17, 20, 23,
    0, 0, 0, 0
  );
  auto mask = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0, 4, 8,
    1, 5, 9,
    2, 6, 10,
    3, 7, 11,
    16, 20, 24,
    17, 21, 25,
    18, 22, 26,
    19, 23, 27,
    -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1);

  auto res = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(vals, mask);
  /*res is:
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 1 2 3 12 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  but should
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` only shuffles inside each 128bit lane. You can combine it with `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64` or `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32` to achieve what you want. Depending on context, there might be more elegant solutions (e.g., where do you get you data from, and what do you do with it afterwards).

Comment: context is a conversion from yuv to rgb
I have a mm256 for r, g, b values and want the result interleaved in a result mm256 register

Comment: See the linked duplicates on [VPSHUFB applies the wrong mask. Or how to better load unsigned 8bit data as 16bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71983800) which explain that `vpshufb` (unlike AVX-512 `vpermb`) isn't lane-crossing, and some options for doing something about it.  Possibly not a duplicate if there's a more efficient way specific to whatever pixel shuffle you're doing, but if you want help with that you should more clearly show the layouts of the input and output formats you're dealing with.  (Or format at this point in the conversion.)

Comment: The question as it is, is indeed a duplicate to, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582438/unexpected-mm256-shuffle-epi-with-256i-vectors. If you want to ask about YUV to RGB conversion, describe your actual input and output format, as well as what operations you are doing on the data (or ask a new question, and we close this one).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unexpected \_mm256\_shuffle\_epi with \_\_256i vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582438/unexpected-mm256-shuffle-epi-with-256i-vectors)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` can’t move these bytes across 16-byte lanes of the vector.

One possible workaround is another shuffle instruction afterwards, here’s an example.

```
__m256i collectRgb( __m256i vals )
{
    // Move the bytes within 16-byte pieces of the vector
    const __m128i gather16 = _mm_setr_epi8(
        0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1 );
    const __m256i gatherMask = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256( gather16 );
    vals = _mm256_shuffle_epi8( vals, gatherMask );

    // Shuffle 4-byte pieces across the complete AVX vector
    const __m256i perm = _mm256_setr_epi32( 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7 );
    return _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32( vals, perm );
}
```