# aarch64-gcc simd inline asm, result always 0

Tags: assembly, gcc, simd, arm64

I try to do SIMD multiplication with inline assembler. However, the result is always zero or (in other cases) gets ununderstandable (for me) values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        double x[2] = {2.0, 3.0};
        double y[2] = {0.0, 0.0};

        asm volatile (
              "fmul %[y].2d, %[x].2d, %[x].2d\n"
        : /* outputs */
          [y] "=&w" (y)
        : /* inputs */
          [x] "w" (x)
        : /* clobbers */
          "cc"
        );

        printf("result = (%f, %f)\n",
               y[0], y[1]);

        return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a73 -march='armv8-a'
```

I always get the output

```
result = (0.000000, 0.000000)
```

but I would expect (4.0, 9.0). Please help!

Comment: First of all, don't do this. Use vector support. Anyway, you are passing the address of the array as input. I couldn't get the compiler to do the load, so you might have to do that by hand.

Comment: Even if you put a load instruction inside the inline asm with an `"r"` input for the pointer, you'd still have the problem of [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259) - as Jester said don't do this, but if you do, ask the compiler for a vector value, not an address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jester said, you have to pass a *value* to the `asm` statement, not a pointer to the datum in question.  The correct type for this value is `float64x2_t` from `arm_neon.h`.  So proceed as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>

int main(void)
{
        double x[2] = {2.0, 3.0};
        double y[2] = {0.0, 0.0};

        asm volatile (
              "fmul %[y].2d, %[x].2d, %[x].2d\n"
        : /* outputs */
          [y] "=&w" (*(float64x2_t *)y)
        : /* inputs */
          [x] "w" (*(float64x2_t *)x)
        : /* clobbers */
          "cc"
        );

        printf("result = (%f, %f)\n",
               y[0], y[1]);

        return 0;
}
```

Note that when you include the intrinsics header, you might as well just use intrinsics directly:

```
int bar(void)
{
        double x[2] = {2.0, 3.0};
        double y[2] = {0.0, 0.0};
        float64x2_t *xx = x, *yy = y;

        *yy = vmulq_f64(*xx, *xx);

        printf("result = (%f, %f)\n",
               y[0], y[1]);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Trivial in the end, but I couldn't see it...

Comment: You don't even need the intrinsics for a multiplication, a plain simple `*` will do.

Comment: Does deref of an intrinsic vector imply aligned access?  If so, you should use `alignas(16) double x[] = {...}`.  Or `alignas(float64x2_t) double x[] = {...}`.  (Include `<stdalign.h>` if this is C rather than C++).

Comment: Does `fmul` write the condition codes?  You can probably omit `"cc"` if you want.