# What is the GCC documentation and example saying about inline asm and not using early clobbers so a pointer shares a register with a mem input?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

The GCC documentation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers-1) contains the following PowerPC example and description:

> ```cpp
> static void
> dgemv_kernel_4x4 (long n, const double *ap, long lda,
>                   const double *x, double *y, double alpha)
> {
>   double *a0;
>   double *a1;
>   double *a2;
>   double *a3;
>
>   __asm__
>     (
>      /* lots of asm here */
>      "#n=%1 ap=%8=%12 lda=%13 x=%7=%10 y=%0=%2 alpha=%9 o16=%11\n"
>      "#a0=%3 a1=%4 a2=%5 a3=%6"
>      :
>        "+m" (*(double (*)[n]) y),
>        "+&r" (n),  // 1
>        "+b" (y),   // 2
>        "=b" (a0),  // 3
>        "=&b" (a1), // 4
>        "=&b" (a2), // 5
>        "=&b" (a3)  // 6
>      :
>        "m" (*(const double (*)[n]) x),
>        "m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap),
>        "d" (alpha),    // 9
>        "r" (x),        // 10
>        "b" (16),   // 11
>        "3" (ap),   // 12
>        "4" (lda)   // 13
>      :
>        "cr0",
>        "vs32","vs33","vs34","vs35","vs36","vs37",
>        "vs40","vs41","vs42","vs43","vs44","vs45","vs46","vs47"
>      );
> }
> ```
>
> ... On the other hand, `ap` can’t be the same as any of the other inputs, so an early-clobber
> on `a0` is not needed. **It is also not desirable in this case. An
> early-clobber on `a0` would cause GCC to allocate a separate register
> for the `"m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap)` input. Note that tying an
> input to an output is the way to set up an initialized temporary
> register modified by an `asm` statement. An input not tied to an output
> is assumed by GCC to be unchanged...**

I am totally confused about this description:

1. For the code there is no relationship between `"m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap)` and `"=b" (a0)`. `"=b" (a0)` will share the register with `"3" (ap)`, which saves the address of the input parameter, and `"m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap)` is the content of the first element of `ap`, so why an early-clobber on `a0` will impact `"m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap)`?
2. Even if gcc allocate a new register to `"m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap)`, I still don't understand what the problem. Since there is tied between `"=b" (a0)` and `"3" (ap)`, so we can still read / write through the register that allocated for `"=b" (a0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an efficiency consideration, not correctness, stopping GCC from wasting instructions (and creating register pressure).

---

`"m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap)` isn't the *first* element, it's an arbitrary-length array, letting the compiler know that the entire array object is an input.  But it's a dummy input; the asm template won't actually use that operand, instead looping over the array via the pointer input `"3" (ap)`

See *[How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432259/how-can-i-indicate-that-the-memory-pointed-to-by-an-inline-asm-argument-may-be)* for more about this technique.

But `"m"` inputs are real inputs that have to work expand to an addressing mode if the template does use them, including after early-clobbers have clobbered their register.

With `=&b(a0)` / `"3"(ap)`, GCC couldn't pick the same register as the base for an addressing mode for `"m" (*(const double (*)[]) ap)`.
So it would have to waste an instruction ahead of the asm statement copying the address to another register. Also wasting that integer register.

Comment: So if set early-clobber, it will cause a "waste" for both the instruction and the register, instead of introduce some wrong logic, is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: @WeiLi: Correct.