# RISC-V GCC Compiler compiles ASM code incorrectly

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv

I am writing an embedded C program to test a hardware IP that I have developed on an FPGA board. I was playing with the RISC-V GCC ASM syntax and found this weird issue.

This is the code that I writing in my C program. Both `write_target` and `base_addr` are declared as volatile uint32_t.

```
// write_target = 0x1F9
asm volatile ( 
  "li   %0, 0x1F9\n"
  : "=r"(write_target)
);


// base_addr = 0x1040_6000
asm volatile (
  "lui %0, %1"
  : "=r" (base_addr)
  : "i" (66566)
);

// base_addr = 0x1040_6000 + 0x0
asm volatile ( 
  "addi   %0, %1, %2\n"
  : "=r"(base_addr)
  : "r"(base_addr), "i"(0)
);

// mem[base_addr] = write_target
asm volatile ( 
  "sh   %0, 0(%1)\n"
  : "=r"(write_target)
  : "r"(base_addr)
);
```

When I look at the compiled dump, I see that it has been compiled to the following:

```
800031e6:   1f900793            li  a5,505        // a5 = 0x1F9 = d'505
800031ea:   f6f42423            sw  a5,-152(s0)   // mem[s0-152] = 505
800031ee:   104067b7            lui a5,0x10406    // a5 = 0x10406 = d'66566
800031f2:   f6f42623            sw  a5,-148(s0)   // mem[s0-148] = 0x10406
800031f6:   f6c42783            lw  a5,-148(s0)   // a5 = mem[s0-148]
800031fa:   00078793            mv  a5,a5         // a5 = a5
800031fe:   f6f42623            sw  a5,-148(s0)   // mem[s0-148] = 0x10406
80003202:   f6c42783            lw  a5,-148(s0)   // a5 = mem[s0-148]
80003206:   00f79023            sh  a5,0(a5) # 10406000 <_tbss_end+0x10406000>
                                                  // mem[a5] = a5
```

I cannot understand why this is the case. I am not very well versed with the inner workings of the RISC-V GCC cross-compiler, so I don't know what am I doing wrong. I cross-checked the syntax and to the best of my understanding it is correct. I am running with -O3 optimization flag.

I would really appreciate any guidance that you all may have.

Thanks!

Update: I am using the <strike>Newlib</strike> gcc compiler from the riscv-gnu-toolchain Git [repo](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain).

The problem I am having is that I want to store the value of `write_target` into `base_addr`. But the compiled code seems to store `base_addr` into `base_addr`.

Comment: Pass `-Wall -Wextra -O3 -fverbose-asm -S` to your `gcc` command. Consider using more [GCC developers options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) to understand what GCC is doing. Of course, read the documentation about [GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/) and consider extending the compile with your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)

Comment: It might be easier to code some routine in assembler, and call that routine from your C program.

Comment: It seems to have endianness issues with "0x1F9". Then `addi` looks like a meta instruction that must be decomposed into load/add/store as RISC architecture has fixed size instructions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `addi` with an immediate zero is disassembled as `mv`, because `mv` is a pseudo-instruction.  The loads and stores are most likely because the C variables are `volatile` (so live in memory) but the asm operands are `"r"`.  Oh, they do mention `volatile` in the text.  (It seems odd to me for a variable named something like `base_addr` to be `volatile uint32_t` rather than a pointer-to-volatile like `volatile T*` for some pointer type.)  So anyway, the `asm("addi"...)`  statement compiles the same as `dspm_base_addr  = base_addr` plus a useless `mv same,same`.

Comment: Other than `0xF91` becoming `0x1F9` (which they didn't even mention), IDK what problem the OP is seeing in the asm, or why they posted such a non-minimal [mcve].

Comment: One bug in the asm source is a missing `"memory"` clobber on the asm statement around the `sh` instruction. (*[How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)*).  Oh, and also it's a store so it has 2 register inputs (one data, one address), but the asm statement tells the compiler one of the operands is `"=r"` write-only on that register, so it won't bother to load that operand into a register, only store the output after.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I can't repro the claimed bug with 0xf91.  https://godbolt.org/z/Mz4WqTrGc shows GCC13 compiling both that asm statement, and plain function that does `return 0xf91;`.  Both the manual `li` and the compiler-generated asm assemble to `lui a0,0x1` /  `addi a0,a0,-111` machine instructions (Godbolt "compile to binary object" mode, making a `.o` and disassembling), and `0x1<<12` (from lui) plus `-111` is `0xf91`.  I also tried RV32 GCC 8.2, the earliest on Godbolt, and it's fine, too, but the OP didn't mention a GCC version (or point that out as a bug.)

Comment: So I'm guessing the bug they might be asking about is constraints for the `sh` store-halfword, where they listed the store-data input as a write-only output.  But we don't know because they didn't say.

Comment: Newlib refers to the C library, not the compiler.  The compiler is gcc.  Newlib is mentioned because it is not glibc.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am really sorry that was a typo on my end. It is `0x1F9`.

Comment: So what problem are you asking about?  Something caused by the bug of telling the compiler the store instruction has a register output instead of input, or something else?  Your question *still* doesn't say.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I just updated the question. Also, if you are asking for the asm syntax for the `sh`, it needs to have a `=` operand. Otherwise the compiler throws an error. And I think that syntax is correct because it does work for some other code that I wrote and tested.

Comment: Ok, then yeah, see earlier comments about the operands to a store.  There's usually no need for inline asm; deref of a `volatile uint16_t*` pointer should work.

Comment: Yeah, I am going through that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you use an output constraint on this assembler directive:

```
// mem[base_addr] = write_target
asm volatile ( 
  "sh   %0, 0(%1)\n"
  : "=r"(write_target)
  : "r"(base_addr)
);
```

That's why GCC never passes `write_target` to the statement.
To match your style, it would need two register input constraints instead, for `write_target` and `base_addr`.

It may be easier to use one `asm` block without any input/output constraints, and clobbers for the hard registers you use in your assembler routine. You can embed multiple lines in one `asm` statement if you embed `\n` into the string. (Convention is to use `\n\t`, to match the compiler-generated instruction indentation.)

Comment: When you say "it would need two register input constraints instead, for `write_target` and `base_addr`" -- do you mean something like this: `asm volatile ("sh %0, 0(%1)" : "r"(write_target) : "r"(base_addr) )`?


Because gcc gives the following error in that case: 
```error: output operand constraint lacks '='
asm volatile ("sh %0, 0(%1)" : "r"(write_target) : "r"(base_addr) );```

Comment: The syntax is `:: "r"(write_target), "r"(base_addr)`. Empty output constraints list and comma-separated input constraints.