# Crash when enabling Interrupts while using an Interrupt Descriptor Table

Tags: gcc, x86, kernel, interrupt, osdev

My qemu emulation just crashes after running init_idt() and then enable_interrupts(). I cant find the error, did i setup the IDT wrong or am i missing something. I am in 32bit protected mode on a x86 machine.

I was hoping this would call interrupt_test() for all interrupts triggered. Then a string would be displayed on the screen.
Here is the Code:

```
#include "idt.h"
#include "screen.h"

struct IDTEntry 
{
    uint16_t base_low;
    uint16_t selector;
    uint8_t reserved;
    uint8_t flags;
    uint16_t base_high;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct IDTEntry idt[256];

void set_idt_entry(int index, uint32_t isr_address, uint16_t selector, uint8_t flags) 
{
    idt[index].base_low = (uint16_t)(isr_address & 0xFFFF);
    idt[index].base_high = (uint16_t)((isr_address >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
    idt[index].selector = selector;
    idt[index].reserved = 0;
    idt[index].flags = flags;
}

void init_idt() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        set_idt_entry(i, (uint32_t)interrupt_test, 0x08, 0x8E);      
    }

    uint32_t idt_ptr[2];
    idt_ptr[0] = sizeof(idt) - 1;
    idt_ptr[1] = (uint32_t)&idt;
    __asm__("lidt (%0)" : : "r"(idt_ptr));
}

void disable_interrupts() {
    __asm__("cli");
}

void enable_interrupts() 
{
    __asm__("sti");
}

void interrupt_test() 
{
    print_str("Yay", 100, 100, to_color(0, 255, 0));
}
```

Comment: Your `lidt` asm statement is missing a `"memory"` clobber or `"m"` operand.  Unless you build with optimization disabled, those assignments to `idt_ptr` are dead stores because you haven't told the compiler the asm statement reads the pointed-to memory, only that it gets a pointer. [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)  You could do `asm volatile("lidt %0" :: "m"(idt_ptr))` to make the whole array a memory operand.  (In that context, it is the whole array, not decaying to a pointer to an array.)

Comment: Probably a good idea to use a `"memory"` clobber anyway, on all your `asm` statements, because you don't want the compiler reordering any memory accesses around anything.  Especially not the stores that set up the IDT itself before you give the CPU a pointer to it.  (`asm` statements without an output operand are implicitly `volatile`, but it's probably a good idea to make that explicit, too.)

Comment: QEMU crashes how?  Use a debugger.  Bochs with its built-in debugger should be very good: it understands x86 details and can pretty-print structures like the GDT or IDT to make sure you set them up the way you intended.

Comment: Your `idt_ptr` is wrong. You do: `idt_ptr[0] = sizeof(idt) - 1;` `idt_ptr[1] = (uint32_t)&idt;` where idt_ptr is an array of 32-bit integers. The idt_ptr structure is actually a 16-bit value (size - 1) followed by a 32-bit base.

Comment: You could create this structure type `struct idt_ptr_t { uint16_t limit; uint32_t base;} __attribute__((packed));` then instead of the array do something like `struct idt_ptr_t idt_ptr = { .limit = sizeof(idt) - 1, .base = (uint32_t)&idt};` and then pass that to LIDT.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Finally got it working. There was a small mistake in my gdt setup and as you pointed out, my idt_ptr wasnt setup correctly. Thanks a lot for helping me :)