# How to mix c code and asm in a c-function?

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I like to do some optimisation and so I like to substitute a line of c code with 2 lines of assembler.

```
rb->am += N
```

the ringbuffer struct `rb` gets incremented by an variable `N`

I am struggling to get the asm right. Here  comes my pseudo code

```
void myFunc(struct rb, const uint16_t N)
...
asm(
"mov w0, %0\n"
"add %1, w0"
: rb->am
: N
: w0
);
```

If I understand the asm keyword its

```
asm(<instruction> : <input operants> : <output operants> : <clobbers>)
```

I am currently don't know how to get the syntax right.

W0 is a register. I assume that I need to tell my compiler that I am using that.

rb->am needs to be resolved into a memory address.

N is a function parameter (like rb).

Any idea how to get this right?

[update]
The target platform is a dspic33 from microchip. I looked up the programmer manual. The only ADD that alters a uint16 variable at the RAM is working against the W0/WREG.

```
ADD f {,WREG} -> Destination = f + WREG
```

Smth like (my pseudo code)

```
MOV WREG, N
ADD addr(rb->am)
```

is needed.
Here a link to my source
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000157g.pdf

Comment: Actually, it's outputs, then inputs.  Check the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  ETA: Just because you are writing part of the code using inline asm [doesn't mean it's going to run any faster](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  The compiler knows more tricks about how to write code than you or I will ever understand.  Trying to write it yourself will almost certainly be slower.

Comment: This is AArch64 I'm guessing, from the W1 register name?  AArch64 instruction have 3 operands, `dst, src1, src2`.  You've already lost vs. an optimizing compiler by using `mov` inside the asm template when it's no necessary.  Using `asm("add %[dst], %[src1], %[src2]" : [dst]"=r"(rb->am) : [src1]"r"(rb->am) : "ri"(N))` to let the compiler pick a destination that's the same or different from the first source.

Comment: If you just want to learn some about assembly so you can look at compiler output to see if the compiler did a good job (and how to write source that can compile more efficiently), you don't need or want inline asm.  See Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “[What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)” and [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) re: using https://godbolt.org/ .  Once you know asm and how C compiles, GNU C asm will be easier to grasp if you ever want to use it.

Comment: actually its dspic33 arch - and its for a bare metal firmware, where we have a racing condition on a data counter. Means I need to make sure that incrementing this counter takes only one cycle. Thats only possible through asm, because the c compiler produces a 2 line code

Comment: You might be able to achieve the desired effect by marking the counter as being an atomic variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
void util_atomic_add(uint16_t * pV, const uint16_t am) {
    asm volatile (
        "add %1, [%0], [%0]\n"
        : "+r"(pV)
        : "r"(am)
    );
}

void util_atomic_sub(uint16_t * pV, const uint16_t am) {
    asm volatile (
        "subr %1, [%0], [%0]\n"
        : "+r"(pV)
        : "r"(am)
    );
}
```

Note:

1. this is a DSPIC33 MCU solution.
2. creating a c-function that only has the ASM code makes life much easier
3. in outputs "=m"(pV) gives you the memory - but in my case as indirect address (W*+offs). ADD and SUB at the DSPIC33 do not support indirect addressing. Means you take "&rb->am" and store it in a register. By doing so you can use direct addressing(pD = &rb->am) "+r"(pD) in inputs "r"(am) takes care that the function parameter is stored at some register
4. check the code on assembler base, compile with optimizations to double
   check

Thx for the fast and good answers

Comment: You probably want a `"memory"` clobber so the compiler knows that memory pointed-to by `pV` is also modified.  As is, you're only telling it that the C variable `pV` (a pointer) is modified.  But the pointer itself actually just an input so you could use `"r"(pV)` for it as well.  [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)

Comment: `""=m"(pV)"` would give you the pointer itself in memory.  `"+m"(*pV)` would tell the compiler the pointed-to memory is a read/write operand (already including square brackets so you'd just expand it as `%0` not `[%0]`).  I don't see "pic" or "dspic" in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html so there might not be a special `"+something"` constraint that could ask for a memory operand with a simple addressing mode if that's actually necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use C?  The obvious C code generates optimal code for the constraints provided.  Well, we had to guess about the structure for rb, but:

```
struct RB {
  int a,b,c,am;
};

void myFunc(struct RB *rb, uint16_t N) {
  rb->am += N;
}
```

generates clean code (XC-DSC v3.00, -O1):

```
_myFunc:
        add.w   w0,#6,w2
        add.w   w1,[w2],[w2]
        return
```

edit:  I 'just' see the note about the atomic increment requirement

Provided inline assembler is not correct, IMHO. "+r" means that the register is changing value, it is not... "memory" is changing value and the register stays the same, this feels more accurate:

```
void alt_util_atomic_add(uint16_t * pV, const uint16_t am) {
    asm volatile (
        "add %1, [%0], [%0]"
        : /*outputs */
        : /*inputs */"r"(pV), "r"(am)
        : /*clobbers*/ "memory"
    );
}
```

Comment: That's correct, `"+r"(pV)` means the pointer variable itself is changing value, taking whatever value the asm leaves in the register it picks for that operand.  See my comments under the OP's self-answer.  Your asm looks sensible.  Another option would be `"+m"(*pV)` to have the pointed-to memory itself as an RMW operand, with the compiler inventing an addressing-mode.